# cvs2git migration failed - NO RCS File Found Error

Tags: git, cvs, cvs2git

I have checked out a copy of CVS repository on local system(windows 7). With the help of cygwin I am trying to migrate local copy of this repository to git(bitbucket) but got stuck at the first phase. Below is the command and error. Can any please guide me here . Any help much appreciated .

Command  :  cvs2git --blobfile=cvs2svn-tmp/git-blob.dat --dumpfile=cvs2svn-tmp/git-dump.dat --username=cvs2git java_apps

Error : Examining all CVS ',v' files...
ERROR: No RCS files found under 'java_apps'!
Are you absolutely certain you are pointing cvs2svn
at a CVS repository?

## Pass 1 complete.

Error summary:
ERROR: No RCS files found under 'java_apps'!
Are you absolutely certain you are pointing cvs2svn
at a CVS repository?

Answer (score 1):

When converting cvs2git, you need the whole *server-side* repository. What you have is a client-side checkout. These are completely different things.

If you just want to take a snapshot of the latest code and push it to git, there's no conversion necessary, just add it to git and push it to bitbucket. But if you want the whole history, you will need to make a copy of the repo from the cvs server.

Comment: I am trying to do it for a longer time but no luck yet . Can you please help me fetch entire repository.

Comment: You cannot fetch the entire repository as an end-user. If you are not the sysadmin of the cvs server, you do not have access to it.

Comment: @Mort, I have access to my repository, but I am confused on how to make a copy of my server side repo on my local. Can you pls guide me on this?